# Добавить кнопку назад в uitableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Смотрите, создал таблицу из массива (на основе tableviewcontroller), добавил поиск - все работает, но никак не могу добавить кнопку возврата на предыдущую view. Проблема в том что в storyboard xcode даёт возможность вставть или navbar (туда можно вставить кнопку назад) или searchbar. А как мне вставить и то и другое?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Положите UINavigationController и протяните ctrl-drag-drop с него на ваш UITableViewController и выберите rootViewController.

Comment: тогда если я нажимаю на поисковую строку вылетает ошибка Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этом руководстве очень доходчиво объяснено
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1

Добавьте еще один нав, например внизу сториборда.

Answer (score 0):

В Storyboard нажмите на ViewController (с которого вы представляете TableViewController). Потом Editor -> Embed in -> NavigationController.
И поставьте NavigationController как Is Initial View Controller.

Если в Storyboard у Вас только TableViewController, то проделайте тоже самое, только с ним.

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier
>   SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class
>   for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Не правильно регистрируете индентификатор ячейки. Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737966/3868736